# Implementing shopping cart using localStorage

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I'm in the process of writing a simple shop for my business, and I'm currently implementing the
cart logic. I use vanilla JS in the client side and communicate with the server via JSON API, I
render everything in the client side.

From my research online, I discovered that some online shops maintain the user cart in their database, so to add/remove/modify an item, you need to send an HTTP request to the server. I don't want to do that, because of the overhead and my idea is to maintain the cart in localStorage and on checkout, send the whole cart at once.

Is this a good idea? What issues can occur when managing a shopping cart in the client side?
I am asking that because I assume there is a reason many online shops manage the user cart in
their database (apart from collecting data on users)

Thanks.

Comment: One issue is that I will need to finish my shopping on the device where I started.

Comment: if your buyers will not have an account on your eshop then you can use localstorage because you will not care if they leave the site and they don't purchase anything. 
If you would like them to have an account, you should use backend developing because you want your subscribers to be able to logout from desktop chrome for example, login from a smartphone and find their cart in place.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I hadn't thought about this. Good to know that doing so is possible.